# defining a generic action that takes a generic action as parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

I am using .Net 4.5. How do I define a generci action that takes in another generic action as a parameter?
When I try the following, the compiler seems to interpret T as an actual type and complains that its definitions is not found:

```
public static Action<Action<T>, IEnumerable<T>> RepeatForEach = (a, x) =>
        {
            foreach (T t in x)
            {
                a.Invoke(t);                
            }
        };
```

I tried the following, none of which worked:

```
Action<T><Action<T>>
Action<Action<T>><T>
Action<Action<T>> where T : object
```

Comment: Where do you define what `T` is?  Even generic types need to be declared somewhere.

Comment: Thats precisely what I am trying to find out. In the last section of the question, I have listed down what I tried to do for this and none of which worked. How do I define what T is?

Comment: It depends what the context is.  You can declare it at the [class level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) (`public class ClassName<T> { ... }`) or [method level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) (`public void MethodName<T>() { ... }`).

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I do not totally agree..how is the above different from defining a generic list as a field?

Comment: It's not. If you declare a List<T> as a field, you must also have T defined in scope.

Comment: If you post a short but complete program illustrating how you intend to use your `Action`, it will give us the context necessary to give you an answer that is more than just a guess.

Comment: @sstan theres not much of a program...was reading through a blog and this idea of writing some general purpose actions came to me....toying around with a class which has a set of such actions which capture common patterns of programming

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that C# doesn't support this level of genericity. You will have to make the enclosing scope generic.

Either have a class:

```
public static class RepeatForEach<T>
{
    public static Action<Action<T>, IEnumerable<T>> Action = (action, enumerable)
    {
        foreach (var element in enumerable)
        {
            action.Invoke(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Or have a method returning the action:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static Action<Action<T>, IEnumerable<T>> GetRepeatForEachAction<T>()
    { 
        return (action, enumerable) =>
        {
            foreach (var element in enumerable)
            {
                action.Invoke(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd also like to put forth an idea that having something do `foreach` on `IEnumerable` is generally a very bad idea. The reason for that would be to achieve side effects and `IEnumerable` is not built for that.

Imagine having an `IEnumerable` created via `yield return`. Then your action might not affect any of the elements (as those may be thrown away and recreated upon enumeration).

Comment: That last point about `IEnumerable` makes no sense to me. What?

Comment: There's a very good read on that by Eric Lippert: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/ In short, `IEnumerable` is only something you can enumerate but it doesn't expose the storage. It is possible that your `action` will not work with the actual entities, only with proxies or copies, and your modifications to them may end up being silently thrown away.

Comment: A sample with two `IEnumerable`s where one remembers the changes and one does not: https://ideone.com/xXOwQ0

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to create a generic type based upon another generic. As said by sstan:

> "Even generic types need to be declared somewhere."

Instead you should try another approach, what about you create an extention method instead? This is my sugestion:

```
public static void RepeatForEach(this Action<T> action, IEnumerable<T> itens)
{
    foreach (T t in x)
    {
        a.Invoke(t);
    }
}
```

So you can call it by:

```
Action<int> t = (int i)=> Console.WriteLine(i);
t.RepeatForEach(myitens)
```